# Prove: $-M = \inf(-E)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I have to prove this exercise for my math study:

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R} \ni M = \sup(E)$ and $-E := ${ $-x$ | $x \in E$ }.

Prove: $-M = \inf(-E)$

I think I've completed the proof by contradiction:

Assume $-M \neq \inf(-E)$
$\Rightarrow \exists$ $-x \in -E$ for which $-x < -M$ (and $x \in E$)
$\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ $x \in E$ for which $x > M$
This is a contradiction because $M = \sup(E)$
So $-M = \inf(-E)$

Is this proof correct? It looks a little bit simple to me. If it's not correct, could you tell me how to proof this exercise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The idea is good, but the proof is not adequate. You would be best off separating the argument into two parts: (i) Show that $-M$ is a lower bound of $-E$ and (ii) Show that nothing greater than $-M$ is a lower bound of $-E$.

Comment: @André Nicolas Ok, I think I proved (i): M = sup(E) $\Rightarrow$ if x $\in$ E then x $\leqslant$ M $\Rightarrow$ -x $\geqslant$ -M. -x $\in$ E by definition, so -M is a lower bound of -E. Is this correct? for (ii), I assumed that M' is a lower bound of -E with M'> M. How do I get a contradiction from this?

Comment: Same technique. Change notation a bit. If $-M'$ is a lower bound for $-E$ and $-M'\gt -M$, show that $M'$ is an upper bound for $E$ that is less than $M$. Again the key fact is that multiplication by $-1$ reverses inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I proved it! It's a pity that you answered in a comment, otherwise I would have rated your answer up.

Comment: I remember this question (or a mild variant) coming up before, so if I had answered it would have been a duplicate. Anyway, the useful thing is that you answered the question. Perhaps you might wish to write a formal answer.

Comment: @André Nicolas Is it correct this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x \in E$
$\Rightarrow x \leqslant M$
$\Rightarrow -x \geqslant -M$
$\Rightarrow -x \in -E$ if $x \in E$, so $-M$ is a lower bound of $-E$

Now assume $-M' > -M$ and $-M'$ is a lower bound of $-E$
$\Rightarrow -M' > -M$
$\Rightarrow M' < M$
$\Rightarrow -x \geqslant -M'$
$\Rightarrow x \leqslant M'$
So, $M'$ is an upper bound that is lower than $M$. This is a contradiction because $M = sup(E)$.
$\Rightarrow -M'$ is not an upper bound of $-E$
$\Rightarrow -M = inf(-E)$                      $\Box$